# How to use Windows Authentication on all but one page for .Net 5.0 Razor Web Pages project?

Tags: iis, razor-pages, windows-authentication

I'm working on a .Net 5.0 Razor pages website that is configured to use windows authentication.  With the follow block being included in launchSettings.json

```
"iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    }
```

Currently when you visit the site you will need to log in before you can view any of the pages.  However, I would like to add a page that can be viewed by anyone without logging in. How can I enable public access or anonymous authentication for a single page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute in action which return specific single page.

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public IActionResult Index()
 {
    return View();
 }
```

[Simple authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-6.0)